# Issue accessing Prediction Trained Model from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-prediction

I'm having a problem accessing a trained model I've created in Google prediction via Google App Engine.
I've implemented all the steps in the article here... https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts

When I deploy to my app engine instance I can run the hosted model sample successfully, however with my own sample model (A1) it fails with the error: Model cannot be found.

The appID is samplrprocessing and the logs show as follows:

**: https://www.googleapis.com/prediction/v1.5/trainedmodels/A1/predict?alt=json&key=MYKEYHERE returned "No Model found. Model must first be trained.">
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~samplrprocessing/1.365876750758965087/stream.py", line 45, in 
    main()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~samplrprocessing/1.365876750758965087/stream.py", line 40, in main
    resp = service.trainedmodels().predict(id="A1", body=bodyLoad).execute()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~samplrprocessing/1.365876750758965087/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~samplrprocessing/1.365876750758965087/apiclient/http.py", line 678, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)**

Has anyone else hit this issue?  I've granted the service account API access to my prediction project so I'm starting to run out of ideas for what's happening.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Just a follow up if there's any ideas on what's causing this or maybe an alternative to what I'm trying to do?  I'm running out of options to try.  Thanks

Comment: OK, I've found another way - do the full OAuth 2 handshake for web applications and store the credentials.  That way it only needs to be authorized once to be run.

Comment: Final update on this - the steps in https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts do work.  The key is you must first train a new model with that same service account on app engine.  I.e. training a model with the general apps domain account you use independently through the prediction API won't work.